# Создание вращающегося 3d-блока с помощью CSS transitions и Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, анимация

Я экспериментировал с `CSS`, пытаясь создать `3d box`, в котором  можно выбрать передний план фигуры с помощью `javascript`.
Он просто меняет имя класса `box divs` и использует свойство `transition` для плавного перехода между  разными местоположениями объекта.

Здесь ссылка на `jsfiddle` с работающим примером http://jsfiddle.net/synthet1c/VdDmA/1/

В настоящий момент это выглядит круто, но это не совсем так, как я хочу ...
Кто-нибудь знает, как я могу сохранять правильную позицию `box` , когда он проходит через  `transition`?

В настоящее время, если `face` куба поворачивается  от 360 градусов до 90 градусов, то `face` будет вращаться на 270 градусов в неправильном направлении.
Я понимаю, почему так происходит, но не могу решить проблему.
Я добавил все префиксы браузеров, но использовал его только в `Firefox`.

```js
var id = function(elem){
    var theId = document.getElementById(elem);
    return theId;
}

function button1(){
    id('front').className = 'front';
    id('right').className = 'right';
    id('back').className = 'back';
    id('left').className = 'left';
}

function button2(){
    id('front').className = 'right';
    id('right').className = 'back';
    id('back').className = 'left';
    id('left').className = 'front';
}   

function button3(){
    id('front').className = 'back';
    id('right').className = 'left';
    id('back').className = 'front';
    id('left').className = 'right';
}   

function button4(){
    id('front').className = 'left';
    id('right').className = 'front';
    id('back').className = 'right';
    id('left').className = 'back';
}
```

```css
.right{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translatez(75px) translatex(-75px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translatez(0px) translatex(0px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.left{
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translatez(75px) translatex(70px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.front{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translatez(150px) translatex(0px);
    transition: all 4s;
}
```

```html
<div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn'>Front</button>
    <button class='btn'>Left</button>
    <button class='btn'>Back</button>
    <button class='btn'>Right</button>
</div>
<div class='house'>
    <div class='face front'>Front</div>
    <div class='face back'>Back</div>
    <div class='face right'>Right</div>
    <div class='face left'>Left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13549568/7394871

Answer (score 6):

### Pure CSS

Кроме того, вы можете делать вращающийся 3D-блок с чистым CSS. Тем не менее, проблема вращения> 180 ° может быть решена только с помощью JavaScript.

```css
body { padding: 5em 0 0; perspective: 45em; }
.faceopt {
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
 z-index: -1;
}
.faceopt + label {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: .25em 1em;
 border-radius: .5em;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 black, 0 -1px 0 #96d1f8;
 background: #65a9d7 linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
 color: white;
 font: 1em Century Gothic, Verdana, sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
 transition: .5s;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.faceopt + label:hover, .faceopt:checked + label { color: yellow; }
.house {
 margin: 5em auto;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 1s;
}
.house, .face { width: 10em; height: 10em; }
.face {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 1em;
}
.front { transform: translateZ(5em); background: rgba(255, 165, 0, .75); }
.back { 
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(30, 144, 255, .75);
}
.right {
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(220, 20, 60, .75);
}
.left {
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(127, 255, 0, .75);
}
#left:checked ~ .house { transform: rotateY(90deg); }
#back:checked ~ .house { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
#right:checked ~ .house { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='faceopt' id='front' class='faceopt' checked>
<label for='front'>Front</label>
<input type='radio' name='faceopt' id='left' class='faceopt'>
<label for='left'>Left</label>
<input type='radio' name='faceopt' id='back' class='faceopt'>
<label for='back'>Back</label>
<input type='radio' name='faceopt' id='right' class='faceopt'>
<label for='right'>Right</label>
<div class='house'>
 <div class='face front'>Front</div>
 <div class='face back'>Back</div>
 <div class='face right'>Right</div>
 <div class='face left'>Left</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле это довольно просто.

Вам просто нужно сделать проверку, чтобы узнать, будет ли разница, назовем ее `dif`, по абсолютной величине между углом, в котором вы сейчас находитесь, и углом, который вы хотите получить,-  более 180°, и если это так, то вы поворачиваете на 360°, минус разность по абсолютной величине. Направление вращения определяется знаком `dif`.

Я также внес некоторые изменения в `CSS`, и если вы хотите больше узнать о том, как создать реалистичный куб, [вы можете изучить мой (действительно) подробный ответ на аналогичный вопрос.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812196/css-3d-animation-how/14421939#14421939)

```js
(function() {
 var btnsEl = document.querySelector('.buttons'), currentAngle = 0;
 btnsEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var b = e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase(), 
   house = document.querySelector('.house'), 
   btns = {'front': 0, 'left': 90, 'back': 180, 'right': -90}, 
   dif = btns[b] - currentAngle%360;
  if(!e.target.classList.contains('btn') || dif === 0) return;
  currentAngle += (Math.abs(dif) > 180) ? 
      (Math.abs(dif) - 360)*Math.abs(dif)/dif : 
      dif;
  house.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
  house.style['transform'] = 'rotateY(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
 }, false); 
}());
```

```css
body { padding: 5em 0 0; perspective: 45em; }
button { cursor: pointer; }
.house { 
 position: relative;
 margin: 2em auto;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 1s;
}
.house, .face { width: 10em; height: 10em; }
.face {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 1em;
}
.front { transform: translateZ(5em); background: rgba(255, 165, 0, .75); }
.back { 
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(30, 144, 255, .75);
}
.right {
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(220, 20, 60, .75);
}
.left {
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5em);
 background: rgba(127, 255, 0, .75);
}
```

```html
<div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn'>Front</button>
    <button class='btn'>Left</button>
    <button class='btn'>Back</button>
    <button class='btn'>Right</button>
</div>
<div class='house'>
    <div class='face front'>Front</div>
    <div class='face back'>Back</div>
    <div class='face right'>Right</div>
    <div class='face left'>Left</div>
</div>
```

### [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4600310)